# maximum number of fields created through CREATE TABLE ? I seem to be stuck at 8

Tags: vb.net, create-table

As long as I stay under 9 fields, the table is created in the database.

From 9 fields on I get an error, which translated into English from Dutch is something like "Record is too big"

(I have added some nonsense fields to the code to get to 9)

```
 Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE tblProject (ProjectID COUNTER, WrittenBy CHAR, ContactDetails CHAR, roetepetoet CHAR, TitleBlock CHAR, popopopopop CHAR, Producer CHAR, xxxooxxx CHAR, ProductionTitle CHAR, PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID))"

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

[image]

the error message is crazy long!

But when I look at the line numbers mentioned in the error message, there is nothing even closely related to what I'm doing as far as I can tell.

I have looked online, but what I found bears no relation to my problem.

Has anyone ever come across something similar and found a workaround?  Your input is most appreciated! as always!

Comment: What database system are you using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL...?)

Comment: How long is your `CHAR` type? You should specify field length, at least in many common databases.

Comment: It is an MS access database - I was not aware that the field length had to be specified. I thought 255 characters was the standard for textfields.  even so, it does not seem very logical to allow 8 fields, but no more.  this is doing my head in!  I even tried creating the table with 8 fields, and afterwards ALTER TABLE to add fields - same error.

Comment: 4000 bytes max, that's 2000 characters or 7 text fields with their default size of 255 chars.  Use, say, CHAR(42) to make a text field smaller or use MEMO.

Comment: Use the `TEXT` keyword instead of `CHAR`.  Also specify the length.   i.e. `TEXT(255)`.  Note that the maximum size of a TEXT field is 255.  Using TEXT without a length will create a MEMO field or you can use the MEMO keyword.

Comment: TnTinmn -- you are my HERO!!!  thank you so much for your help!  I feel my headache disappearing! -- how do I mark the question as answered?

Comment: Your reply will not be seen by @TnTinMn unless you precede his username with @.

Comment: @TnTinMn -- you are my HERO!!! thank you so much for your help! I feel my headache disappearing! -- how do I mark the question as answered?

Comment: @Mary thx for the hint! Learn somerhing new every day here!!

Comment: @svenliegeois, I added an answer that you can mark as the solution if you want to.  see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I do not know why you receive the "Record is too large" error when using the [CREATE TABLE statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql) with the `CHAR` keyword to specify the field type. In Access, you receive this error when the record is created and the sum of the entered characters in all fields exceeds the maximum limit.

A work-a-round is to use the `TEXT` keyword instead of the `CHAR` (or `CHARACTER`) keyword.

In regards to the record size limit, see [Access specifications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c):

[image: Character Limit 4000]

This limit appears to be approximately 2000 Unicode characters without compression.

To enable compression on a TEXT field, you need to apply the `WITH COMPRESSION` attribute to the field definition.

For example: `WrittenBy TEXT(255) WITH COMPRESSION`